# Prevent user from deleting specific text from input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an conteneditable with predefined text inside:

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.some-class{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>Hello <span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span> people!</div>
```

I want to prevent users from deleting `<span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span>` from it.

I guess I should check what text is being deleted when user press back space on onChange event. But I don't know how to check if deleted content is just on letter like `H` or the whole div `<span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span>`

Comment: Can I ask why you have content you don't want edited in a content editable element?

Comment: Please don't link to external code when you can easily add it here.

Comment: @Craicerjack this is very specific case, where user can add some predefined values that he/she shouldn't be able to deleted latter in process.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of assigning `contenteditable=true` to the entire container, break down the contents into separate span elements and assign it there like so:

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.some-class{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div><span contenteditable=true>Hello </span><span class="some-class" contenteditable=false>Dont delete me!</span><span contenteditable=true> people!</span></div>
```

Edit: If you don't want to change the markup, you can use jQuery to search for the string of text that isn't supposed to be deleted and then make sure it persists any attempts to remove it.

```js
$('#div').on('input', function() {
  var span = $('.some-class').text();
  if (span.indexOf('Dont delete me!') < 0) {
    $('.some-class').text('Dont delete me!');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.some-class {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div" contenteditable=true>Hello <span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span> people!</div>
```

Comment: This is not really what I want. User can input a 100 paragraphs into that content editable and also can add many `<span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span>` with different text inside. I cannot afford to wrap some of them with `contenteditable=true` and some with `contenteditable=false` which will required complex code to implement this logic. Also this solution creates a lot of unnecessary HTML markup. Want I want is to detect what text node was removed from contenteditable.

Comment: You are close, but users still can delete if they highlight whole element. I guess what I am really asking is if there is a way to detect what text was deleted from input. Was it just one letter `H` or whole  element `<span class="some-class">Dont delete me!</span>`? Then I can check if that element contain a specific class or tag and put it back if true or allow deletion. Really appreciate you time and help.